# disable notepad++ updates on install or through script - Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, notepad++, updates, deployment

I deploy notepad++ to several computer labs where end users don't have administrative rights. I am able to deploy the software, but I need to turn off automatic updates so they aren't getting popups when the next version comes out. Is there a way to do this either via command line switches on install or after install by modifying the registry, or other files?
I am currently installing with:
    "npp.6.6.9.Installer.exe" /S

Comment: did you check or ask on http://sourceforge.net/p/notepad-plus/discussion/

Comment: I looked briefly, but didn't find anything. I'll take a closer look.

Answer (score 3):

For fresh installs, a good solution is the following:

**%ProgramFiles%**\Notepad++\**config.model.xml**

Modify the line:

From:

< GUIConfig name="noUpdate" > ***no*** < /GUIConfig >

To:

< GUIConfig name="noUpdate" > ***yes*** < /GUIConfig >

So essentially new user profiles will be populated with a NoUpdate set to yes.

This is especially useful for SCCM and silent deployments.

Comment: Umm you did not read correctly dude.

The answer above mine is a modification to the %users% realm, my instructions makes sure that all future users do not get impacted as well.

Please if you got nothing good to comment, don't comment at all.

Answer (score 2):

There's a couple of ways you could do it. If you don't deploy the `updater` folder then the updating functionality won't work (and you don't appear to get any error messages). If you just want to disable the option you'll need to edit the user's config.xml file, e.g.

```
C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++\config.xml
```

The line you're after is:

```
<GUIConfig name="noUpdate" intervalDays="15" nextUpdateDate="20140606">no</GUIConfig>
```

Change the 'no' to 'yes' and the auto-update checking will stop.